# Good references for currents and potential theory?

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry

I am looking for a good reference on currents and potential theory. I am already familiar with differential geometry, distribution theory and potential theory in the complex plane (at the level of the book of Ransford).

Note : I already asked a more vague reference request in [Some references for potential theory and complex differential geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84320/some-references-for-potential-theory-and-complex-differential-geometry) . I am now looking only for a book on currents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are looking for a geometric measure theoretic treatment of currents, Leon Simon's "Lectures on Geometric Measure Theory" provides an excellent and rather self contained exposition.

Comment: thank you ! I'll look into it.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I am looking for something with a more "differential geometric" point of view